# Reading geometry of a .gdb with large number of polygons

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, cursor

I've got a .gdb loaded into my ArcMap 10 that has about 9 Million polygons. I would like to get data from each polygon to include its geometry and certain fields from its row in the attribute table. I have done some reading [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/reading-geometries.htm) for geometry, and [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/data-access-using-cursors.htm) for accessing the attribute table data, but I am unfamiliar with using the `arcpy.da` module along with cursors.

Could somebody provide me with an example of how I may loop through each polygon in the layer (it is the only one in my current map) and extract its linear ring of points and several field values?

Comment: @Midavalo Well I am working some small samples using the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` but I am trying to understand `GetParameterAsText`. The [docs](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/getparameterastext.htm) says it gets the value from a parameter list, but what list? Where is it? To me a parameter list is the listing of accepted arguments in a function header.

Comment: The GetParameterAsText is used when you are accessing parameters from an "ArcToolbox" form. If you are running from the Python prompt or IDLE (or other IDE) you can just set your parameters in your script. There are several examples here (gis stackexchange) or in the arcpy documentation showing how to use the cursors.

Comment: @jbchurchill Okay, so if I wanted to use the only layer in my current map, how would I set that in the Geoprocessing > Python pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `da.SearchCursor`, but `GetParameterAsText` is for retrieving inputs from users for script tools, not pulling properties from a geometric object. If you aren't writing this to be used as a tool in the GUI, you won't need it. You may be thinking of `row.getValue()`, but I don't think the new `da.SearchCursor` uses it, they just return a list per row, with each field value as an item in that list. Make sure when you're researching these tools, you're getting the Data Access module cursors, that confused me when I first started.

I've found it easiest to read through the geometries using the `SHAPE@` tokens as documented in [Reading geometries](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/reading-geometries.htm), rather than the `Shape` field name(s). If you want the output to be written in human-readable text, use the `SHAPE@XY` (or even `SHAPE@WKT` or `SHAPE@JSON`) tokens.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = 'somedir/somefile.gdb'

# OID@ is also a token, included for illustrative purposes
fields = ['OID@', 'SHAPE@XY'] #
features = 'feature_class'

# Using "with" on cursors as well as file io has saved me some grief
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(features, fields) as table:
    with open('file.txt', 'w+') as f:
        for row in table:
            obj, geom = row[0], row[1]
            output = '{0}, {1}\n'.format(obj, geom)
            f.write(output)
```

You could also write it to a CSV, for example, just make sure to use `'wb+'` to write to it in binary. Of course, you don't have to include the OID, and if you wanted to define multiple variables for your fields, you'd usually call the whole list, like `obj, geom = row`.

Comment: When I have a `.gdb`, what exactly is the last part in the string `C:\Base\something.gdb\the_layer`? When I add data in ArcMap, the `the_layer` part shows up to select. Why is it that I have to chose that last part rather than just selecting the `.gdb` and loading everything?

Comment: It would be the feature class. The standard practice (since many arcpy functions require it, like `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()`) is to set the `env.workspace` variable. The [workspace](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/current-workspace.htm) acts as a "current working directory" of sorts, and allows you to refer to feature classes (in your case, `the_layer`) without needing the whole path. Using Python from within ArcMap handles the workspace for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I used. I just refer to the variable taxParcel which is named "Parcels (2013)" in the table of contents. It doesn't even need the full path to the dataset. When I run my script I type.

```
execfile(r"C:\Path\ToMy\Script\myscript.py")
```

There is a lot more going on in my script than you need (I'm getting the values from a pre-populated dictionary called "recordDict").

```
taxParcel = "Parcels (2013)"
updFields = ["Field01", "Field02", "Field03"]
def writeParcelValues(taxParcel, updFields):
    try:
        n = 0
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(taxParcel, updFields) as sCur:
            for row in sCur:
                while n < len(updFields):
                    fldGISName = updFields[n]
                    if not fldGISName == 'ACCTID':
                        try:
                            if fldGISName in recordDict: 
                                row[n] = recordDict[fldGISName]
                            else:
                                print("WARNING - " + fldGISName + " is not in the Property Information List")
                        except (IndexError, NameError) as err:
                            print("No Account Found")
                            print(err)
                            break
                    print("FLD-GIS: " + fldGISName)
                    n += 1
                sCur.updateRow(row)
    except RuntimeError:
        print("RuntimeError: Possibly you don't have an edit session or you are not editing the Parcels Layer.")
```